# How to Render streaming output in Browser? (python flask)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

How can I display the result of the Response in Browser

The endpoint is `/model_feed`

```
@app.route('/model_feed')
def model_feed():
   return Response(getModelFeed())
```

the `getModelFeed()`

```
def getModelFeed():
  while True:
    output = {"gesture" : "K"}
    output = json.dumps(output)
    yield (output)
```

If we sent a request to the endpoint `/model_feed` then the server continuously returns the output `{"gesture" : "K"}`. How to display it in the browser using HTML or code for python flask template. we can implement camera streaming by `<img id="bg" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">` this HTML code. I'm looking for a html code like as shown above.

Comment: you use template for this, better check flask docs

Comment: @johnII i can't use `render_template()` because in that page i already implemented the webcam streaming on the same page. I have tried ajax to get the response but can't catch that response

Comment: where is your ajax implementation?

Comment: @johnII I have added the ajax code

Comment: should i use return instead of yield

Comment: What browser are you using ?? For chrome go to develloper tools and see what response your is returned by your request

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi the content type is `Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8` but i have coverted that to json using `jason.dumps()`.

Comment: `json.dumps` is a byte text, so what i get is that whenever you open that certain app ( /model_feed ) in your browser, you continuously get `{"gesture" : "K"}` on your browser right? but can i ask what is the use of it? it'll just lag the browser screen, it won't give you that string multiple times

Comment: actually I have developed a web app based on neural network. So that I need to display the prediction output. In that some hand gesture capture through webcam streaming and predict some output and send that back to my web page. I have only posted the needed code here.